# Why does my header not "hug" the edges of the browser viewport?

Tags: html, css

HTML noob here.

Given the following html and css files, can someone tell me why my header does not hug the left and top edge of the viewport?

In other words, why is there white space above the grey box, and to its left, even though margin and border are set to 0?

[image: picture of problem]

.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap" >
        <div id="headerbar">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

.css file:

```
p {
    font-family:verdana;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 3em;
}

#headerbar {
    width:3000px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:30px;
    background: grey;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is default `margin: 8px` on `body`. You can remove that using:

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

**NOTE:** 
You set `border: 0; margin: 0;` to `div` where these are defaults. You can remove them there.

Answer (score 1):

Give the body a 0 margin.

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: lol, downvote for what?

Comment: Maybe because you write correctly _body {margin: 0;}_ but in your code you have a lot of mess? `HTML` has `margin/padding 0` by default, `body` has the `zero padding` too by default.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, the body has a default margin. Add this to your css file:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}
```